# Cloning 128GB SSD to a new 240GB SSD

Tags: ssd, cloning

I suppose this is a duplicate, but I didnt find it. Sorry if it is obvious.

The situation is this. I am installing a new computer with a 128GB SSD, leaving only 40GB of free space. I suppose space will run out in a year or two, so I'm checking out what would it involve to change the SSD to a 240GB later on.

What software would you suggest and what is the procedure. I found this https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/ssd-to-ssd-cloning-software.html . The motherboard has only one SATA port so I'd have to do the cloning on an another computer. Could there be complications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have zero experience with EaseUS so can't comment and won't recommend.

I won't recommend commercial software either when there's free alternatives that do the job perfectly. [Macrium Reflect (free)](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), mentioned in the first answer is a good tool that I've used and can vouch for its reliability and easy of use.

The one I use the most for this purpose, however, is the Linux based and FOSS [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/).

In any case you would be using external bootable media, USB or CD, to boot from and run the software. Macrium Reflect can be installed in Windows and the bootable media prepared from the software itself as well as the backup process; with Clonezilla users burn the media directly, using the downloaded ISO file, boot from it and follow the instructions.

> Could there be complications ?

YES, everything has the potential for complications, life itself is (very) complicated.

However, if the users know how to use the tools and what to do the chance for complications is very small.

The case described in the question is very typical - cloning a drive to a larger one - and doesn't require user actions prior to the backup itself.

Make sure that everything required is being backup up or cloned so, in this case and regardless of the software, you want to **clone the whole drive** and then, in the new drive, expand the system partition to use the full (new) capacity.

Comment: I used EaseUS and at the first there was chkdsk scan. Afterwords the system worked fine, but I thought it was a bit slower than before. Not sure if it was the cloning or smth else I had done.

Answer (score 0):

EaseUS is pretty good.

I like using [**Acronis True Image**](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/computer-backup/) (costs money) or [**Macrium Reflect**](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree). And if possible do it with their recovery option where you boot the PC from a USB or CD that has Acronis/Macrium on it.

It is a very straightforward process and should not have any complications.